# Using eventtrigger without clicking

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have a CheckBox that's set up like so:

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="ViewTypeCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding ViewType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Refresh}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </CheckBox>
```

This functions as it's supposed to. When checked or unchecked by mouse click, the command is fired in the ViewModel.

You see the checkBox is databound to a bool property ("ViewType") that regularly turns from true to false and viseversa in response to user input.

The problem is I need the EventTrigger to fire when checked or unchecked by the ViewModel.

I've tried changing the "EventName" to "Checked", "IsChecked" and "UnChecked" but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any additional code I need to implement? How would I get this to work?

Comment: If the VM is controlling ViewType, why can't that just call Refresh() itself?

Comment: May help [Link](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/07/22/commands-versus-event-triggers-in-mvvm/)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Well you see the Command in question doesn't reside in any VIewModel. It's actually located in an assembly. I just figured it'd be easier to explain, or for people to get the general idea if I put Refresh. What I really need to execute is the command; NavigationCommands.GoToPage

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need Interaction.Triggers,**

WPF provides support for [commands](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/) out of the box.

Try simplifying your XAML by using a command attribute instead. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call some code when the `ViewTypeCheckbox.IsChecked` changes its value, you can simply register an event handler to the PropertyChanged event of your view model (assuming it implements INotifyPropertyChanged), then call the code when the property ViewType changes:

```
myViewModel.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(onPropertyChanged);
...
private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName=="ViewType")
    {
      // Do your stuff here
      // Ex. fire the Refresh Command
    }
}
```

This can be done in the ViewModel class itself or whatever you need.
To complete the example I add a short implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the viewmodel class:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler!=null)
        {
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

  ...

  // property definition to bind to ViewTypeCheckbox.IsChecked
  private bool _viewType;
  public bool ViewType
  {
    get { return _viewType; }
    set
    {
       if (value != _viewType)
       {
         _viewType = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("ViewType");
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger to execute your action. You can do it in the viewmodel when the property change.

```
public Boolean ViewType
{
    get 
    { 
        return this.something; 
    }

    set 
    { 
        this.something = value;
        if (true == this.something)
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No doubt this would work. The thing is, "Refresh" was simply placed there for explanative reasons. The command I wish to execute resides in an assembly library. That's what makes it tricky for me. The command is actually called "NavigationCommands.GoToPage".